# Ploty, single multicolored line

Tags: python, plotly

I have a data frame with a date and two columns.

This is not the real data. The plot is actually working better here than with my real data. In my real data, the 3 lines are continuous, over here at least two additional lines are broken.

How to get one line that changes color instead of three separate lines?

The data looks like this:

| date | P1 | c1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/01/07 | 2 | 0 |
| 2021/01/08 | 4 | 1 |
| 2021/01/11 | 6 | 1 |
| 2021/01/12 | 6 | 0 |
| 2021/01/13 | 4 | -1 |
| 2021/01/14 | 2 | -1 |
| 2021/01/15 | 2 | 0 |

c1 shows when p1 is rising or falling. I want to plot p1 colored by c1. I don't want multiple lines.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

import pandas as pd

data = {
  "date": ['2021/01/07', '2021/01/08', '2021/01/11', '2021/01/12','2021/01/13','2021/01/14','2021/01/15'],
  "p1": [2, 4, 6, 6,4, 2,2],
  "c1":[0,1,1,0,-1,-1,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])


fig=px.line(df, x='date1',y='p1',color='c1')
#fig=px.line(df, x='Date',y='t1')
#fig=px.line(df, x='date1',y='p1',facet_col='c1')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I have edited your question. I think it was downvoted because you forgot to ask a question. This is fixed now. Read [ask] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Plotly doesn't support this functionality natively but you can plot separate lines for each unique 'c1' value and then join them together, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = {
    "date": ['2021/01/07', '2021/01/08', '2021/01/11', '2021/01/12','2021/01/13','2021/01/14','2021/01/15'],
    "p1": [2, 4, 6, 6, 4, 2, 2],
    "c1":[0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

colors = {0: 'blue', 1: 'green', -1: 'red'} 

fig = go.Figure()

for c1_val in df['c1'].unique():
    df_sub = df[df['c1'] == c1_val]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_sub['date'], y=df_sub['p1'], mode='lines', line=dict(color=colors[c1_val])))

fig.show()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Christian, unfortunately this produced the same result on the big dataset (only about 700 values).  It just seperates the plot into a blue, red and greeen zones and does not intermingle them.

Comment: I'll try a bar chart, maybe it will work better there.